# await setTimeout is not synchronously waiting

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I know that `setTimeout` is an API which runs asynchronously and I wanted to run it synchronously. Using `async/await` like below should print `bla bla` first but I get `bla` first.

```
  async function testing(){
    console.log("testing function has been triggered");
      await setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("bla bla")
      }, 4200)
    console.log("bla");
  }
```

Comment: `await` only does anything useful when you `await` a promise.  Since `setTimeout()` does not return a promise (it returns a timerID), your `await` does nothing at all here.  You can wrap `setTimeout()` in a small function that returns a promise that resolves when the timer fires and use that wrapper instead.  That still won't be synchronous in the true sense of the word, but the function execution would be internally paused.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesn't return a `Promise`, so you can't `await` it.

You can wrap `setTimeout` in a function that returns a `Promise` which is fulfilled once the timer expires. You can `await` this wrapper function.

```js
function createCustomTimeout(seconds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('bla bla');
      resolve();
    }, seconds * 1000);
  });
}

async function testing() {
  console.log('testing function has been triggered');
  await createCustomTimeout(4);
  console.log('bla');
}

testing();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
async function testing(){
  console.log("testing function has been triggered");
   console.log(await printFunction());
  console.log("bla");
}

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const printFunction = async () => {
  await timeout(4200);
  return "bla bla"
}

testing();
```

Please support with answered if it solved your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Import `setTimeout` from `node:timers/promises`:

```js
import {setTimeout} from 'node:timers/promises'

const res = await setTimeout(1000, 'result')

console.log(res) // Prints 'result' after 1000ms
```

See: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers-promises-api