# JS Promise function call that returns object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, return

I have a async fetch function that waits 2 seconds and returns a object:

```
async function fetch() {
    var object;
    await setTimeout(() => { object = { name: 'User', data: 'API Data' } }, 2000);
    return object;
}
```

I want to display the object when the initialization is completely done (after 2 seconds)

```
fetch().then((val) => {
    console.log("DONE!"); 
    console.log(val.name);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("ERROR!");
    console.log(err);
});
```

The code prints both DONE and ERROR `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`

I have tried with Promise, no luck

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let request = fetch();
    if (request !== undefined)
        resolve(request);
    else
    reject(request);

}).then((val) => {
    console.log(val);
});
```

How can I properly check that `fetch()` has returned a value before printing without changing the inside of the function. I can delete the async and await in it but I am unable to edit it (I.E. adding a Promise inside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on requirement

> I can delete the async and await in it (fetch function) but I am unable to edit it (I.E. adding a Promise inside)

The only way I see is to override window.setTimeout function to make it to return a promise. That way you will be able to await it and there will be no need to modify your `fetch` function.

```js
const oldTimeout = window.setTimeout;
window.setTimeout = (fn, ms) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    oldTimeout(() => {
      fn();
      resolve();
    }, ms);
  });
};

async function fetch() {
  var object;
  await setTimeout(() => {
    object = { name: "User", data: "API Data" };
  }, 2000);
  return object;
}

fetch()
  .then((val) => {
    console.log("DONE!");
    console.log(val.name);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("ERROR!");
    console.log(err);
  });
```

NOTE: For anyone without this requirement - please, use other answers to this question or check [await setTimeout is not synchronously waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439266/await-settimeout-is-not-synchronously-waiting) for additional details/explanations. This kind of overridings are very confusing due to everyone expect common and well-known functions to behavior in a way described in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot await the setTimeout function, this is because your function returns undefined. You have used the promise in the wrong way. Below code will fix your issue.

```
function fetch() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ name: "User", data: "API Data" });
        }, 2000);
    });
}

fetch()
    .then((val) => {
        console.log("DONE!");
        console.log(val.name);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("ERROR!");
        console.log(err);
    });
```

And remember that there is no need to change the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setTimeout` does not actually return a promise, which means you cannot use await with setTimeout, that's why the `var object;` is returned instantly as `undefined`.

To solve this issue, you simply need to wrap `setTimeout` around a promise.
Like so:

```
function setTImeoutAwait(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, time);
    });
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
async function fetch() {
    var object;
    await setTImeoutAwait(1000).then(() => {
        object = { name: "test" };
    });
    return object;
}
```